# Synonymize [forwarding] and [email-forwarding]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I'm not fully convinced that they're the best tags, but [forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) and [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding) seem to be covering the exact same territory.

[forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) has usage guidance:

> Generically refers to the operation of re-sending an email message delivered to one email address on to a possibly different email address.

[email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding) does not.

However, [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding) is a more specific tag name and should be the master, I think. That means:

1. <del>The usage guidance for [forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) should be copied/moved to [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding)</del>
2. [forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) should be made a synonym of [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding)
3. [forward](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward), currently a synonym of [forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) should be changed to be a synonym of [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding)
4. [forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forwarding) and [email-forwarding](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-forwarding) should be merged

Comment: I've added usage guidance to [tag:email-forwarding]. The rest requires a moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed.

Apologies for the delay, when I first saw this question I was just about to do the merge but got called away. Then my brain fell apart and I completely forgot about it.